# Why is this not displaying information in a UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-cloud-firestore, swift5

I would really appreciate any help on this. I'm very new to coding, and have no luck implementing this feature so far. I'm looking to populate a `UITableViewCell` with information gathered from Firestore, namely: `title`, `username` and `content`. I've been able to print the 'title' array successfully, but have not been able to actually populate this into the cells.

This is the `HomeViewController`, where my `UITableView` is:

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

@IBOutlet weak var logoutButton: UIButton!


var postArray: [String] = []
var documents: [DocumentSnapshot] = []

let db = Firestore.firestore()
let currentUserID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

    // Find the UserIDs of people following
// Where Field for those UserIDs in "Posts"


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    getFollowingPosts()
    configureTableView()
    }

func getFollowingPosts() {
    let searchForFollowing = db.collection("users").document(currentUserID!).collection("Following")
    searchForFollowing.getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
        for documents in snapshot!.documents {
            let followedUID = documents.get("uid")
            print(followedUID!)
            
            self.db.collection("posts").whereField("uid", isEqualTo: followedUID!).getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in
                for documents in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    let uid = documents.get("uid") as! String
                    let title = documents.get("Title") as! String
                    let ProfilePictureURL = documents.get("ProfilePictureURL") as! String
                    let username = documents.get("username") as! String
                    let content = documents.get("Content") as! String
                    self.postArray.append(title)
                    print(self.postArray)
                }
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
    }

func configureTableView() {
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.register(PostTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "PostCell")

    // remove separators for empty cells
    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
    // remove separators from cells
    tableView.separatorStyle = .none
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    postArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostCell", for: indexPath) as! PostTableViewCell
    let post = postArray[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

}

This is my `PostTableViewCell`:

```
class PostTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var usernameLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var contentLabel: UILabel!


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        addSubview(usernameLabel)
        addSubview(titleLabel)
        addSubview(contentLabel)

    }


    

}
```

If anyone could help, this would be massively appreciated. Like I said, I've been struggling a lot with this one.

Comment: What addSubview(usernameLabel) and other lines for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't seem to be setting the data onto anything in the cell.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostCell", for: indexPath) as! PostTableViewCell
    let post = postArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.titleLabel.text = post
    return cell
}
```

Also, modify the register method if you're using nib

```
func configureTableView() {
    //...
    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "PostCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "PostCell")
    //...
}
```

Note: Make sure that the nib file has nib's identifier set as "PostCell".